# Installing Report Manager on a separate server with SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Is it possible to install the IIS part of SSRS 2008 on a separate server. We have one database server and one web server. Is it possible to install the database part of SSRS2008 on the database server and the web part (Report Manager,..) on the web server?

Are there any guidelines for this scenario?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to install the Report Manager on another server.

[Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159272.aspx). and [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143718(SQL.90).aspx).

Answer (score 5):

First of all, there is no IIS part of SSRS 2008. SSRS no longer depends on IIS and pipes traffic directly from http.sys into the SSRS server instead of through IIS.

can you seperate your catalog server (the databases) from the application server (which has the ReportServer web service and the ReportManager application)? Yes you can but be forewarned that you will require a license of SQL Server for each server.